# Misleading XSD validation error in Java

Tags: java, validation, xsd

I'm having a problem with the text of an error message provided by the XSD Validation libraries in Java. In my case, it seems that Apache Xerces is used under-the-hood.
I find the error from Java very misleading to the least.

The error I'm getting from Java is:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'root' is not complete. One of '{subnode1, subnode2}' is expected.

But another XML editor, XMLSpy 2004, says this :

> Mandatory elements expected in '' after 'subnode1': subnode2, subnode3

The second error seems to be much more accurate here, since no subnode1 is missing. However, subnode2 and subnode3 both are.

Here is my XML file:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <subnode0/>
    <subnode1/>
</root>
```

This is the XSD I used:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root" type="NodeType">
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="NodeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="subnode0" type="subnode0_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="subnode1" type="subnode1_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="subnode2" type="subnode2_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="subnode3" type="subnode3_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="subnode0_Type">
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="subnode1_Type">
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="subnode2_Type">
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="subnode3_Type">
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is my Java code which calls the validation API.

```
public class XsdErrorTextMain {

    private final static DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    private final static SchemaFactory schemaFactory;

    static {
        try {
            final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Document xmlDocument = readXmlFile("file.xml");
        final Schema schema = readXsdFile("schema.xsd");

        runXmlValidation(xmlDocument, schema);
    }

    private static void runXmlValidation(final Document xmlDocument, final Schema schema) throws SAXException {
        try {
            final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

                @Override
                public void warning(final SAXParseException exception) {
                    return;
                }

                @Override
                public void error(final SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                    displayValidationError(exception);
                }

                @Override
                public void fatalError(final SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                    throw new RuntimeException("A fatal error was raised during the validation", exception);
                }
            });

            validator.validate(new DOMSource(xmlDocument));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void displayValidationError(final SAXParseException validationError) {
        System.out.println("Line: " + validationError.getLineNumber());
        System.out.println("Column: " + validationError.getColumnNumber());
        System.out.println("Message: " + validationError.getMessage());
    }

    private static Document readXmlFile(final String path) throws IOException, SAXException {
        try (final InputStream xmlInputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path).openStream()) {
            return documentBuilder.parse(xmlInputStream);
        }
    }

    private static Schema readXsdFile(final String path) throws IOException, SAXException {
        final Document xsdDocument = readXmlFile(path);
        return schemaFactory.newSchema(new DOMSource(xsdDocument));
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?
Do you know of other implementations which might compute error messages more accurately?
Any input is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the message given to you by what you refer to as XMLSpy 2004, is misleading. Given the "unbounded" maxOccurs on subnode1, one cannot really say with certainty what should come after the last encountered subnode1: should there be another, or more of subnode1, and then a subnode 2 and 3?

The only thing for sure is that one of subnode1 or subnode2 may follow, at the point the error was raised.

And this is exactly what the other message you're getting (Xerces you say, btw it matches that of standard .NET) tells you...

Imagine that someone uses this information to build an editor that drives the user through the steps required to build a valid XML (e.g. Intellisense, or some context menus in a graphical editor). Which one do you think is better in guiding the user? I would call on the Xerces message as being the correct one, simply because once I've filled in a subnode1, the XML Spy 2004 message would keep suggesting just a node 2 and 3 (why 3 if I didn't filled in a 2? What if I want to keep adding subnode1s?)

My point being, it can depend on what you expect from these messages. My personal take though is that the Xerces (and as indicated, .NET as well) message is the correct one, for the type of task I've described. Some people may find it too iterative, i.e. you will be told to "prepare" a subnode3 only after you've hit a subnode2... your issue, I guess...

But then imagine another scenario, where the whole set of nodes you've shown is wrapped in an optional sequence, and that sequence is followed by a mandatory subnode4.... should then the message, in your case, read `'' after 'subnode1': subnode2, subnode3, subnode4`. And then, what if the optional sequence I was referring to above, is repeating?

In the end, given the nature of XSD models, one could implement this "look ahead" to give you possibilities... the thing is, options easily compound to a point where the information becomes useless... Whereas what's next is always a good thing to now.

Comment: This explanation is very interesting! I now understand the first error message better.